# Test-Path on non-existing drive is giving different results when using X: vs X:\ (when using the [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] type)

Tags: powershell, parameters

Since the X: drive doesn't exist on this machine (and C: does), I'm curious why these 4x give different results - particularly the difference between `X:` and `X:\`

```
PS C:\> Test-Path ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'X:')
True
    
PS C:\> Test-Path ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'X:\')
False

PS C:\> Test-Path -Path ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'C:')
True

PS C:\> Test-Path -Path ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'C:\')
True
```

I made objects out of the X: drive test-case and (visually) compared their properties, which appear identical:

```
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$GoodPath = 'X:\'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$BadPath = 'X:'

PS C:\> $GoodPath, $BadPath | Format-List -Property *


Mode              : darhsl
BaseName          : X:\
Target            : 
LinkType          : 
Name              : X:\
FullName          : X:\
Parent            : 
Exists            : False
Root              : X:\
Extension         : 
CreationTime      : 12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
LastAccessTime    : 12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
LastWriteTime     : 12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
Attributes        : -1

Mode              : darhsl
BaseName          : X:\
Target            : 
LinkType          : 
Name              : X:\
FullName          : X:\
Parent            : 
Exists            : False
Root              : X:\
Extension         : 
CreationTime      : 12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
LastAccessTime    : 12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
LastWriteTime     : 12/31/1600 4:00:00 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM
Attributes        : -1
```

Trace-Command is offering some clues as to where parameter binding is failing.  The lines that are different are indicated with a `-->`

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression {Test-Path -Path $GoodPath} -FilePath 'C:\GoodPath_Results.txt'
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression {Test-Path -Path $BadPath} -FilePath 'C:\BadPath_Results.txt'
```

## X:\ vs X:

```
GoodPath_Results.txt (X:\)

ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Test-Path]
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [X:\] to parameter [Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String[]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             ENCODING arg into collection
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [DirectoryInfo], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], coerceElementType
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Argument type DirectoryInfo is not IList, treating this as scalar
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.String]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT arg type to param type using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT SUCCESSFUL using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo: [X:\]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

```
BadPath_Results.txt (X:)

ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Test-Path]
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [.] to parameter [Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String[]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             ENCODING arg into collection
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [DirectoryInfo], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], coerceElementType
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Argument type DirectoryInfo is not IList, treating this as scalar
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.String]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT arg type to param type using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT SUCCESSFUL using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo: [.]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     DYNAMIC parameter object: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemItemProviderDynamicParameters]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

## C:\ vs C:

```
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$GoodPath = 'C:\'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$BadPath = 'C:'
```

```
GoodPath_Results.txt (C:\)

ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Test-Path]
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\] to parameter [Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String[]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             ENCODING arg into collection
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [DirectoryInfo], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], coerceElementType
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Argument type DirectoryInfo is not IList, treating this as scalar
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.String]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT arg type to param type using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT SUCCESSFUL using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo: [C:\]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     DYNAMIC parameter object: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemItemProviderDynamicParameters]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

```
BadPath_Results.txt (C:)

ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Test-Path]
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [.] to parameter [Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String[]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             ENCODING arg into collection
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [DirectoryInfo], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], coerceElementType
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Argument type DirectoryInfo is not IList, treating this as scalar
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.String]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Trying to convert argument value from System.IO.DirectoryInfo to System.String
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT arg type to param type using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo
--> ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 CONVERT SUCCESSFUL using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo: [.]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     DYNAMIC parameter object: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemItemProviderDynamicParameters]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-Path]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

Can anyone offer some insight into:

- Why do `X:` and `X:\` behave differently in this case?
- Why don't `C:` and `C:\` share this behavior?

Comment: `Test-Path ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'X:')` yields `$true` for you, ONLY because you're using Windows PowerShell, and because Windows PowerShell uses .NET Framework and .NET Framework developers for some strange reason decided that calling `.ToString()` to a `DirectoryInfo` instance should return the object's `Name` property instead of it's `FullName`

Answer (score 0):

Directly constructing a `DirectoryInfo` with a non-existing path creates a semi-valid object. **I wouldn't recommend it.** The path is not normalized and subsequent use depends on the .Net process CWD, which is usually different from PowerShell's CWD. It's also missing all the PS* `NoteProperty` members. `PSPath` is especially useful in the pipeline, since it usually binds to `LiteralPath`.

There's a check in the `DirectoryInfo` constructor that sets the `DisplayPath` of a drive root path ("X:") to `'.'` and that `DisplayPath` is what is returned by the default `ToString()`:

```
:~> $a = 'C:\', 'C:', 'X:\', 'X:'
:~> $a | % { [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$_ } | % ToString
C:\
.
X:\
.
```

The above values are used as arguments when you pass a manually created `DirectoryInfo` as the `Path` parameter in `Test-Path`. This explains why only `'X:\'` returns false (`'X:'` is mistaken for `'.'`).

In contrast, `Get-Item` only returns objects of existing items, which use resolved absolute paths as their string representation. Using such objects (either as arguments or via the pipeline) should be preferable:

```
:~> $ErrorView = 'CategoryView'
:~> $a | Get-Item | % ToString
C:\
C:\Users\Elias
ObjectNotFound: (X:String) [Get-Item], DriveNotFoundException
ObjectNotFound: (X:String) [Get-Item], DriveNotFoundException
```